# A wrapper over system clipboard

Tags: c#, excel, winapi, clipboard

I am developing an application which requires that whenever a specific item is copied, it's contents are modified before it is placed on System clipboard. The whole intention ,here, is to not share this data with other applications running in case it is accidentally copied/pasted by user.

can someone throw some light on it if they experienced the same problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Copied from where exactly?

Comment: Accidentally copied? C# objects other than visible contents of controls will never be accidentally copied to the clipboard. You will have to call some code that copies them to the clipboard. `Clipboard.SetDataObject(myObject);`

Comment: @jmcilhinney : well, its an excel application. I am trying to model the copy from Excel sheet/cell/ranges.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes : as it's an excel application, user might copy a range containing some sensitive data and use it elsewhere as it is now available on clipboard. I want to modify the data before it is pasted on clipboard.

Comment: I don't understand. The data is on screen? The user can just make whatever he wants with your data. What trying to mess with the clipboard will bring you?

Answer (score 0):

You can [install a thread-wide message filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) and check for the `WM_COPY` message.  Then data can't be copied from standard controls without your code knowing about it.

Comment: Is there a way that when pressed ctrl + c keys in combination we can capture it before it reaches the system clipboard?